# List comprehension only returns last iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, networkx

I'm trying to create a population of adjacency matrices with different random weights for which I am using the code underneath. My problem however is that upon running this, all the weights are that of the last iteration of the list comprehension? On printing these `adjacencylists` during generation, it works fine, however, the output of the `getPopulation` function is 5 times the same parameter set.

It feels like this would be an easy fix, but something (I think possibly very basic) is missing. Maybe a problem where deep copy is needed or something?

Already tried using normal for-loops, print statements etc.

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(["Sadness", "Avoidance", "Guilt"])
G.add_edges_from([("Sadness", "Avoidance")], weight=1)
G.add_edges_from([("Avoidance", "Sadness")], weight=1)
G.add_edges_from([("Avoidance", "Guilt"), ("Guilt", "Sadness")], weight=1)
parameters = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)

def getRandParamValue(adj):
    for p in np.transpose(adj.nonzero()):
        adj[p[0], p[1]] = adj[p[0], p[1]] * np.random.uniform()
    print(adj)
    return adj

def getPopulation(size, initParam):
    return [getRandParamValue(initParam) for i in range(size)]

getPopulation(5, parameters)
```

Upon printing the output in the getRandParamValue function it works fine:

```py
[[0.         0.40218464 0.        ]
 [0.07330473 0.         0.7196376 ]
 [0.53148413 0.         0.        ]]
[[0.         0.34256617 0.        ]
 [0.01773899 0.         0.12460768]
 [0.1401687  0.         0.        ]]
[[0.         0.11086942 0.        ]
 [0.01449088 0.         0.04592752]
 [0.07903259 0.         0.        ]]
[[0.         0.01970867 0.        ]
 [0.00589168 0.         0.00860802]
 [0.06942081 0.         0.        ]]
[[0.         0.01045412 0.        ]
 [0.00084878 0.         0.00713334]
 [0.0024654  0.         0.        ]]
```

However, the output of `getPopulation` isn't identical to the previous output, while this should be expected:

```py
[matrix([[0.        , 0.01045412, 0.        ],
         [0.00084878, 0.        , 0.00713334],
         [0.0024654 , 0.        , 0.        ]]),
 matrix([[0.        , 0.01045412, 0.        ],
         [0.00084878, 0.        , 0.00713334],
         [0.0024654 , 0.        , 0.        ]]),
 matrix([[0.        , 0.01045412, 0.        ],
         [0.00084878, 0.        , 0.00713334],
         [0.0024654 , 0.        , 0.        ]]),
 matrix([[0.        , 0.01045412, 0.        ],
         [0.00084878, 0.        , 0.00713334],
         [0.0024654 , 0.        , 0.        ]]),
 matrix([[0.        , 0.01045412, 0.        ],
         [0.00084878, 0.        , 0.00713334],
         [0.0024654 , 0.        , 0.        ]])]
```

The parameters matrix is just the following:

```py
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: if you want the same result in your list than the one printed, just add `.copy()` in the `return` of `getRandParamValue` such as `return adj.copy()`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, Why is this needed though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: @BasChatel it is because numpy arrays are mutables, not sure I can provide more explanation, maybe read [this](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-mutable_vs_immutable/PT-mutable_vs_immutable.html), (not on stackoverflow) it could help you to further understand.

Comment: I want to add a comment on what you do, if you define `size` with a big number, all the value will tend towards 0, as each time you multiply the previous value with a value between 0 and 1, see by yourself with printing the last element of the list of 100 elements: `print (getPopulation(100, parameters)[-1])`. Just to be sure you now what will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is as follows:

```
def myfunction(L):
    L[0] += 1
    return L

my_outer_list = [1,2,3]
newlist = myfunction(my_outer_list)

print(newlist)
> [2, 2, 3]
print(my_outer_list)
> [2, 2, 3]

newlist[2]=-1
print(newlist)
> [2, 2, -1]
print(my_outer_list)
> [2, 2, -1]
```

I've passed the object `my_outer_list` to the function.  Then that object gets modified, and the object is returned.  So now `newlist` and `my_outer_list` aren't just equal, they are two different names for the very same thing.  Things I do to that object change the object, and you see those changes no matter which name you use.

This is what's happened to you.  If I had instead had `myfunction` return `L.copy()`, it would have returned a copy of `L` rather than exactly `L`.

So you should return `adj.copy()`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! You all helped me a lot :)